# Minimum cell height with UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

Is it possible to set minimal height for cell? I use dynamic:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 83.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But I need to set minimal height for cell when my `news title label text` is in one line.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Have you tried creating a constraint in your custom `UITableViewCell`'s view of `height >= 60.0`?

Comment: how exactly did you solve it? can you provide some instructions?

Comment: Drag and drop a View on top of UITableViewCell and set constraints Leading, trailing, top and Bottom as 0. Set height constraint as >= ExpectedMinimumSize.

Comment: You can do it without an extra View. If you have a large image and a text, just set the image bottomConstraints to >= x

Answer (score 11):

There is a trick which is answered by @Hytek. For this you have to give the constraint for minimum height.

For example: If there is one `UILabel` into your table cell and you want that `UILabel` increase the height as per the dynamic content. And you have code it like below.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 83.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

It will increase your label height when content is bigger but it also will decrease when your content is small. So if you expect that label should have minimum height then you have to give a height constraint to your `UILabel` in a way that `height >= 30.0` to your label.

[image]

This way your `UILabel` will not decrease the height less then `30.0`.

Answer (score 9):

Got it. Made it work as below.

Drag and drop a View on top of UITableViewCell and set constraints Leading, trailing, top and Bottom as 0. 
Set height constraint as >= ExpectedMinimumSize.

In heightForRowAtIndexPath Delegatemethod:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

In ViewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60; // required value.
```

Comment: Also worked for me in swift 3:

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }`
In ViewDidLoad:
`self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60`

Comment: I can't get this to work. My cell has a label and a switch, both centered vertically with respect to the superview, no vertical margins. At runtime, the cell's height is reported as `44.6667` even though I specified an estimatred height of `60` (like in this answer). It works if I add top/bottom margins to the label or switch, but I would have to caluclate those to give about 60 and feels inelegant...

Answer (score 4):

Set a contentViews heightAnchor to your least required height .

Swift 4.2 version programatically

`contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: <Required least Height>).isActive = true`

Answer (score 1):

At the auto layout code of the custom cell (either Interface Builder or programmatically), add the appropriate constraints.

E.g. (Programmatically in custom cell)

```
    UILabel * label = [UILabel new];
    [self.contentView addSubview:label];
    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label);
//Inset 5 px
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[label]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[label]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
// height >= 44
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.mainLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:44.0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return (UITableView.automaticDimension > minimumHeight) ? UITableView.automaticDimension : minimumHeight
}
```

Comment: please consider describe what you did in order to solve OP's problem

Comment: This approach worked for me somewhat but auto resizing becomes disabled in my case which kind of defeats the purpose. Leaving the row height as UITableView.automaticDimension and setting a height constraint on the view works as needed for me.